# can lsload print in standard integer format?

Tags: load, lsf

I am using `lsload -I io` in LSF to measure IO use on our nodes and if the io values gets above 9999, it turns to scientific format like `1e+04` or `4e+04`. Is there a way to get the actual numbers in integer (rather than scientific) format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find a way to do it through the existing lsload command, but you can do it by using the API to write a simple command to fetch it for you.

Here's some (very ad hoc) sample code to return the 'io' load on all hosts as a float, you can probably modify it to do fancy stuff like just give you the hosts you want etc.

ls_ioload.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <lsf/lsf.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct hostLoad* hL;
    int numhosts = 0;
    char* hostnames[256];
    char* indices[] = { "io" , NULL };
    char** nlp = indices;
    int i;

    hL = ls_loadinfo(NULL,&numhosts,OK_ONLY|IGNORE_RES,NULL,hostnames,0,&nlp);
    if( !hL ){
        ls_perror("ls_ioload");
        exit(-10);
    }

    if( nlp[0] ){
        printf("HOST\t%s\n",nlp[0]);
        for(i = 0; i < numhosts; i++){
            printf("%s\t%f\n",hL[i].hostName,hL[i].li[0]);
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

You can compile with something like:

```
gcc -o ls_ioload -I$LSF_ENVDIR/../9.1/include ls_ioload.c $LSF_ENVDIR/../9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/liblsf.a
```

Sample output on my little single host cluster:

```
[~]$ lsload -I io
HOST_NAME       status    io
hostA               ok  1e+4

[~]$ ./ls_ioload
HOST    io
hostA   12074.595703
```